# Appending TXT files in VBA and opening in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, append, txt

Newbie here.

So I have a dozen of these TXT/DTA files that look something like this and I want to stack them side by side. **I want each file appended to the right, merged into one big file**

[image: Data files]

Not knowing much about VBA I looked around and merged a few codes that seems to do it for xlsx files but doesn't for DTA files which is what I have. The code asks for a folder and loops through the files one by one.

```
Sub AllWorkbooks()
   Dim MyFolder As String   'Path collected from the folder picker dialog
   
   Dim MyFile As String 'Filename obtained by DIR function
   Dim wbk As Workbook 'Used to loop through each workbook
On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Opens the folder picker dialog to allow user selection
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
.Title = "Please select a folder"
.Show
.AllowMultiSelect = False
   If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then 'If no folder is selected, abort
MsgBox "You did not select a folder"
      Exit Sub
   End If
MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\" 'Assign selected folder to MyFolder
End With
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder) 'DIR gets the first file of the folder
'Loop through all files in a folder until DIR cannot find anymore

'---Open the first file only
Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
Workbooks(MyFile).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy Workbooks("CV Combined.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
Workbooks(MyFile).Close SaveChanges:=False
MyFile = Dir

Do While MyFile <> ""
   'Opens the file and assigns to the wbk variable for future use
   Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=MyFolder & MyFile)
   'Replace the line below with the statements you would want your macro to perform
    Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
    Workbooks(MyFile).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy Workbooks("CV Combined.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1)
    Workbooks(MyFile).Close SaveChanges:=False

wbk.Close SaveChanges:=True
MyFile = Dir 'DIR gets the next file in the folder
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What "side by side" should mean? Do you want adding the next file content to the right of the existing range, or at the end of the file? Then, the DTA extension may mean a lot of things... Can you open such a DTA file with NotePad/WordPad and can you see the content as you show us in your picture? Are those files `Tab` delimited? Do they correctly open in Excel, split by columns?

Comment: Side by side means I want them appended to the right of each file (i.e. in parallel). I can append them vertically using Power Query. Yes, the image is from Notepad. Yes, Excel opens the file correctly split by columns but I want to automate the process for other batches. Yes, the file is `Tab` delimited.

Comment: Should I understand that all the files in that specific folder are of type DTA, or are there TXT file, too?

Comment: The extension is DTA. But I read online that it's basically a TXT file. Perhaps that was an oversimplification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyFile = Dir(MyFolder)` returns only the filename in `MyFile` so to open the first file use `Workbooks.Open (MyFolder & MyFile)`. When the text file is opened the sheet name is the filename so `Workbooks(MyFile).Worksheets("Sheet1")` needs to be `Workbooks(MyFile).sheets(1)`. Because your text file only has data in column A on row 1 `Selection.End(xlToRight)` will go the last column on the sheet `XFD1` and then `Selection.End(xlDown)` will go to the last row `XFD1048576`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub AllWorkbooks()

    Dim MyFolder As String   'Path collected from the folder picker dialog
    Dim MyFile As String 'Filename obtained by DIR function
    Dim wbDTA As Workbook 'Used to loop through each workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsDTA As Worksheet, rng As Range
    Dim iCol As Long, n As Long
    
    'Opens the folder picker dialog to allow user selection
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Please select a folder"
        .Show
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then 'If no folder is selected, abort
            MsgBox "You did not select a folder"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\" 'Assign selected folder to MyFolder
    End With

    Set ws = Workbooks("CV Combined.xlsm").Sheets(1)
    iCol = 1

    'Loop through all files in a folder until DIR cannot find anymore
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder)
    Do While MyFile <> ""
        
        Set wbDTA = Workbooks.Open(MyFolder & MyFile, False, False)
        Set wsDTA = wbDTA.Sheets(1)
        Set rng = wsDTA.UsedRange
        
        rng.Copy ws.Cells(1, iCol)
        iCol = iCol + rng.Columns.Count + 1 ' add blank column
        n = n + 1
        wbDTA.Close SaveChanges:=False
        MyFile = Dir 'DIR gets the next file in the folder
 
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox n & " files imported from " & MyFolder, vbInformation

End Sub
```